# android: when to use onStart(), onStop()?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I've read several posts that describe the difference between `onStart()` and `onResume()`: `onStart()` is called when the activity becomes visible, `onResume()` is called when the activity is ready for interaction from the user. fine.

I've always just added code to `onPause()` and `onResume()`, and never bothered with `onStart()` and `onStop()`.

Can anyone give some concrete examples of what you might do in `onStart()`, vs. `onResume()`? Same goes for `onStop()` and `onPause()`, how is `onStop()` useful? I must be missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`onStop()` will (for example) be called when you leave the activity for some other activity (edit: almost. see commonswares comment about dialog themed activities).
For example if you use `startActivity()` in activity A to start activity B. When you press back in activity B you will return to activity A and `onStart` will be called.

This differs from some of the reasons `onPause` might be called without `onStop` being called. If for example the screen times out or you press the standy button `onPause` will be called, but probably not `onStop` (depending on memory available and whatnot), so it is a "lighter pause". onStop will be probably be called eventually even in this case, but not immediately.

**Ok, but what's the use**

Often there is no specific use, but there might be. Since your activities will keep its memory  state on the stack even after you start some other activity, that stack will increase with the number of activities started (height of the stack).
This can lead to large memory usage in some applications. After a while the framework will kick in and kill some activities on the stack, but this is rather blunt and will probably mean a lot of states to be retained when returning.

So an example use for `onStart/onStop` is if you want to release some state when leaving an activity for another and recreate it when you get back.
I have used it to set listadapters to null, empty image caches and similar (in very specific applications). If you want to free the memory used by visible views in a listadapter you can recreate it in onstart and let the views be picked up by the gc. This will increase the likelyhood that the rest of the memory state of the activity will live on.

Some resources can be deemed good enough to save while the activity instance is alive and some only when it is on the front of the stack. It is up to you to decide what is best in your application and the granularity of create/start/resume gives you that.

Comment: "onStop() will be called when you leave the activity for some other activity" -- actually, it will be called when your activity is no longer visible. If a dialog-themed activity comes to the foreground, `onStop()` is not called.

Comment: Good point. The calling activity might still be visible in the background in that example (and recycling stuff then would be bad). I was showing an example of where it happens and how i have used that to reduce the memory usage, but this is a good exemption. As a general rule it is still good. I have yet to see stacks of dialog activities calling each other.

Comment: Oh, without a doubt, dialog-themed activities are unusual.

Answer (score 1):

onStart() works after onCreate() ended its task. 
It's a good place to put a broadcastReceiver or initialize some state about the UI that should display consistently anytime the user comes back to this activity.

onResume() works when you come back to your Intent or Activity by pressing the back button. So onPause will be called every time a different activity comes to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

i think that your question is pretty explained here on the doc : read about the [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: `onStart()` works after `onCreate()` ended its task. `onResume()` works when you come back to your `Intent` or `Activity` by pressing the back button.

Comment: @Hamza that's not true. anytime your activity goes from being not visible to visible, onStart() is called.

Comment: No man! I did onStart() on my application. It was because, I wanted to fetch data from webservice after loading the activity. Check this by Android Guide [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: See, `Called when the activity is becoming visible to the user.

Followed by onResume() if the activity comes to the foreground, or onStop() if it becomes hidden.`. Check the link above.